# Thinkpad X1 Yoga with Ubuntu 20.04 touchpad suddenly requires additional finger for every action (point, tap, scroll)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, gestures

so I'm working on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga (Gen 6) with Ubuntu 20.04 installed and my touchpad is suddenly and without discernible reason requiring me to use an additional finger for every action:

Usually I can move the pointer and tap-to-click with just one finger but as of half an hour ago, I need to use 2 fingers to do that. Same with scrolling, which normally takes 2 fingers, now I can only scroll with 3 fingers on the touchpad.

I was in the middle of some basic text editing when the pointer suddenly wouldn't move anymore until I tried scrolling which moved the pointer and helped me figure out the rest.

I've tried rebooting but nothing.

Does anyone have an idea how to diagnose what's wrong here and ideally fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I saw this is also happening to other people (me included on 22.04).
https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/r9k7d3/two_fingers_on_touchpad_register_as_one_but_one/
If rebooting doesn't help it might be a hardware problem. Did you try another OS (from a boot drive for example)?